# How to deal with JSON response in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
function EntryCtrl($scope, Restangular){
 console.log("*** EntryCtrl");
 $scope.roles= Restangular.all("roles").getList();
 console.log("*** EntryCtrl: " +  JSON.stringify($scope.roles));
}
```

The console output is:

```
*** EntryCtrl: {"restangularCollection":true}
```

When I use a rest browser plugin to make the same rest call, I get:

```
[
 {
     "name": "dev"
 }
]
```

I cannot figure out how to get Angular to process the response same as the rest browser plugin.
My ultimate goal is to just get the role name, "dev", in Angular.
On an Angular page, I want to use "ng-show" on a link using the role name, like this:

```
<a href="" ng-show="roles.contains('')>Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$scope.roles= Restangular.all("roles").getList().$object;
```

from the [doc](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#lets-code)

> Does a GET to /accounts 
>   Returns an empty array by default. Once a value is returned from the server
>   that array is filled with those values. So you can use this in your template

```
$scope.accounts = Restangular.all('accounts').getList().$object;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:

> Restangular uses promises. Instead of doing the "magic" filling of objects like $resource

So to get the response from the server, you have to use .then callback like so:

```
Restangular.all("roles").getList().then(function(response){
    $scope.roles = response;
});
```

And in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="role in roles">{{role.name}}</li>
```